# Переходы между уровней

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет, наверно я уже надоел) задаю и задаю вопросы.
Я и не знаю как правильно задать этот вопрос. Вопрос заключается в том, что нужно как то сделать ограниченный переход на другие уровни т,е (допустим есть 7 уровней и надо сделать так, что бы пока не пройдешь или не соберешь какую нибудь вещь не сможешь перейти с 2 на 3, с 3 на 4 (на данный момент я нуждаюсь в варианте последовательного прохождения уровня одним за другим))

[image]
Примерно так выглядят переходы у меня.

Comment: Вам нужно предварительно ознакомиться с теорией по вопросу "стейт-машины". Это самый правильный вариант решения данной задачи. Ссылки в помощь: https://habr.com/post/160105/ и https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/3.6.php

Comment: @AK, стоит оформить, как ответ.